# Getting PLS-00201 error while creating a type in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG(
F_TABLE_MODIFIED        VARCHAR2(40),
F_OPERATION_PERFORMED   VARCHAR2(30),
F_ROWS_ALTERED          INTEGER, 
F_LAST_UPDATED_BY       VARCHAR2(200),
F_LAST_UPDATED_DATE     TIMESTAMP);
```

I am trying to build a type with the same structure:

```
create or replace type TYPE_EVOL_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG as object
(
F_TABLE_MODIFIED        T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.TABLE_MODIFIED%TYPE ,
F_OPERATION_PERFORMED   T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.OPERATION_PERFORMED%TYPE,
F_ROWS_ALTERED          T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.ROWS_ALTERED%TYPE , 
F_LAST_UPDATED_BY       T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.LAST_UPDATED_BY%TYPE ,
F_LAST_UPDATED_DATE     T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.LAST_UPDATED_DATE%TYPE
);
```

Getting the below error message in creating the Type :

> Error(3,25): PLS-00201: identifier 'T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.TABLE_MODIFIED' must be declared.

Previously I tried to create the Type without using `%TYPE` and just simply copying the parameter definition and it worked. 
But I don't want to make any changes in Type when I make any changes in Table.

Comment: your column names start with a  `F_` prefix,  for `%TYPE` you must write them exactly like in the create-table-statement.

Comment: ohh even with the same name like :
create or replace type TYPE_EVOL_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG as object
(
F_TABLE_MODIFIED        T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.F_TABLE_MODIFIED%TYPE ,
F_OPERATION_PERFORMED   T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.F_OPERATION_PERFORMED%TYPE ,
F_ROWS_ALTERED          T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.F_ROWS_ALTERED%TYPE , 
F_LAST_UPDATED_BY       T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.F_LAST_UPDATED_BY%TYPE ,
F_LAST_UPDATED_DATE     T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.F_LAST_UPDATED_DATE%TYPE
);

its giving the same error.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work like that, see APC's excellent answer

Answer (score 2):

The `%TYPE` syntax is for use in PL/SQL declarations. Unfortunately we cannot use it when creating SQL objects. Same goes for `%rowtype`.

It would be highly neat if we could, because one common use of `create or replace type` would be to build table APIs as you want to do. However, it would be too complicated to manage referencing constructs in the data dictionary; bear in mind that Types can be used to define other objects including Table columns.

So alas, you need to declare the Type with explicit datatypes for its attributes:

```
create or replace type TYPE_EVOL_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG as object
    (
    F_TABLE_MODIFIED        VARCHAR2(40) ,
    F_OPERATION_PERFORMED   VARCHAR2(30),
    F_ROWS_ALTERED          INTEGER , 
    F_LAST_UPDATED_BY       VARCHAR2(20) ,
    F_LAST_UPDATED_DATE     DATE
);
```

Obviously you also need to sync it manually whenever the structure of any  T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG column changes. But you would have to do this anyway if you added or dropped a column.

Alternatively you can define the type as a PL/SQL record in a package. That would allow you to use the referencing syntax.

```
create or replace package game_config as    

    TYPE_EVOL_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG is record
    (
        F_TABLE_MODIFIED        T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.F_TABLE_MODIFIED%TYPE ,
        F_OPERATION_PERFORMED   T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.F_OPERATION_PERFORMED%TYPE,
        F_ROWS_ALTERED          T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.F_ROWS_ALTERED%TYPE , 
        F_LAST_UPDATED_BY       T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.F_LAST_UPDATED_BY%TYPE ,
        F_LAST_UPDATED_DATE     T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG.F_LAST_UPDATED_DATE%TYPE
    );

    -- or even
    TYPE TAB_EVOL_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG is table of T_C_EVO_GAME_CONFIG_CHANGE_LOG%rowtype;
end;
```

It depends how you want to use the Type in your broader application.