# Insert into table from collection type oracle 12c - ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle 12.1 I thought I can query the table types in 12c.I get error ORA-00902: invalid datatype when I try to execute this package.
I even tried using cast multiset,but still same error.

I know we can create object at database level and then query, but I don't want to.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test123 AS
 TYPE typ1 IS RECORD(col1 VARCHAR2(100),col2 VARCHAR2(100));
 TYPE tab_typ IS TABLE OF typ1 INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
v_tab tab_typ;

PROCEDURE p1;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test123 AS

PROCEDURE p1 IS
 BEGIN
  SELECT c1,c2 BULK COLLECT INTO v_tab FROM tabx;            
   INSERT INTO taby
     SELECT * FROM TABLE(v_tab);
  END;
END;
/

EXEC test123.p1;
--ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

Comment: *"I know we can create object at database level and then query, but I don't want to."* - Why not? Moreover, what's the need to go for  collections  if all you need is to perform a simple `insert into taby(col1,col2) select c1,c2 from tabx` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, in order to select from a collection in the way you're trying, it needs to be defined at the database level. You can't use locally defined collection types in SQL statements. As soon as you remove your types from that package and instead do `create or replace type typ1 as object (col1 varchar2(100), col2 varchar2(100));` and `create or replace type tab_type as table of typ1;` your procedure would work. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683875/how-do-i-select-from-bulk-collected-table-of-records-type/

Comment: How many columns are present in your table `taby`. If there are more than 2 columns or the datatype of those two columns are different than `varchar2` then it might end up in problem. However assuming everything intact in your code, it should work fine as in `Oracle 12c R1` querying a type within the scope of a plsql block is very well allowed. Check again the version of your database. Read the link for reference https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_C00OCGQ88DL0XDOHKS282J6Q4.html

Comment: @XING Thanks for the prompt reply.Yes, the datatypes in the table: taby is varchar2 same as the record type.You can try yourself and see if you get error.

Comment: @RajA I have already shared the link which shows that a `Type` declared in PLSQL scope can be used in `SQL` statement in a block. Can you run this statement and share the output with us `Select * from v$version;`.

Comment: @XING The select * from table works fine in Cursor or for Loop, but does not when I use it for INSERT

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The select * from table works fine in Cursor or for Loop, but does not
>   when I use it for INSERT Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition
>   Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 -
>   Production CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production TNS for Linux: Version
>   12.1.0.2.0 - Production NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

After carefully revisiting your query, I found that you were correct. `Insert` doesnot work. And it looks correct as well. We already have `FORALL INSERT` to get data inserted from the collection to a table. Hence the necessasity of having a additional `INSERT as Select Statement` is ruledout. However you can use the `SELECT` statement using a collection in `Where` clause of the query. 
To make and insert you can simply follow the below steps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test123 
AS
PROCEDURE p1 IS
 BEGIN
  SELECT c1,c2 BULK COLLECT INTO v_tab FROM tabx;  

  ForAll rec in 1..v_tab.count
   INSERT INTO taby
    values v_tab(rec);
     --SELECT * FROM TABLE(v_tab);
  END;
END;
/
```

Incase you want to use the `Type` declared under `PLSQL` scope in `Select` statement, you can use as below:

```
DECLARE
 TYPE typ1 IS RECORD(col1 VARCHAR2(100),col2 VARCHAR2(100));
 TYPE tab_typ IS TABLE OF typ1 INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
 v_tab tab_typ;
BEGIN

 SELECT col1,col2 BULK COLLECT INTO v_tab FROM tabx;  

  DELETE FROM taby
    WHERE (col1,col2) in (Select * from table(v_tab)); 

END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I forgot about the ForAll. Thanks.But in my case I have the collection filled first and then have different inserts to different tables with joins and filter conditions.So I wanted to use the collection in a Select statement

Comment: @RajA `Insert` with `select statements` is not going to work. You can then think of `GTT` to hold intermediate results for joins.