# Add values in a loop to a Collection of Records

Tags: oracle, plsql

I come from a MS SQL Server background so if I am going about this completely wrong please let me know.

I have a table of Lists, each of these Lists have Tasks. These tasks have dependencies on each other. We want to copy a List and its Tasks and those Tasks dependencies. There are other associated records for each Task as well.

A previous Oracle developer created a procedure to carry out the copying. Along with other stuff there is a loop from a Cursor which gets all the Tasks in the List being copied.

It loops through the cursor creating the new tasks and anything associated with them based on the old tasks. I have recently introduced the dependencies table.

A row would be: Id, SuccessorId, PredecessorId, DependencyType.

Now working on what I have already if I was in SQL Server I would create a table variable of OldId, NewId  and with each new Task inserted based on an old one I would also insert a row into the table variable. Then I could INSERT SELECT the old dependencies using the table variable to get the new Ids.

In Oracle I have this at the package level:

```
  TYPE old_id_new_id_row       IS RECORD(old_id list_tasks.id%TYPE, new_id list_tasks.id%TYPE);
  TYPE t_old_task_ids_new_task_ids IS TABLE OF old_id_new_id_row INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Then in the proc declaration

```
    lt_old_ids_to_new_ids  t_old_task_ids_new_task_ids;
```

And I am trying to add a record to this a I go through the loop but there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. I can `BULK COLLECT INTO` it say the values of the old Ids for the dependencies but I'm not sure then how to update the `new_id` value for each row.

This example [here Example 5-21](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#BABFBHII) is about as close as I can find but I am struggling to see an example with records being added one at a time. So it could be:

```
SELECT lt.id AS old_id, -1 AS new_id
    BULK COLLECT INTO lt_old_ids_to_new_ids
    FROM list_tasks lt
    WHERE lt.list_id = 96;
```

But as I insert the new Task records in and get their Ids how would I get the New Id into match the Old Id?

As I say I am open to completely different, clever methods of doing this but I am working with the code I have. This feels like it should be a lot more simple than it has proved so far.

Edit: Apologies for my question not being clear. This isn't the procedure in question as it's too complex and too much irrelevant stuff going on, this is me trying to understand the concepts. Hopefully illustrates roughly what I am trying to do. I've updated in light of the one answer given as of this moment. This won't compile currently because of TABLE(mycoll) which I swear worked before with the Table Type collection.

```
    PROCEDURE test_temp_table(list_id       IN lists.id%TYPE
                            , io_cursor   IN OUT t_ref_cursor) IS
   
    CURSOR lt (pc_list_id    lists.id%TYPE) IS
        SELECT id
        FROM list_tasks
        WHERE list_id = pc_list_id
        ;        
        
    TYPE old_id_new_id_row2 IS RECORD(old_id NUMBER, new_id NUMBER);
    TYPE t_old_task_ids_new_task_ids2 IS TABLE OF old_id_new_id_row2 INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids t_old_task_ids_new_task_ids2;
    c PLS_INTEGER;


  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  
    FOR ltr IN lt(list_id) LOOP  
        tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids(tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids.count +1).old_id := ltr.id;
        --This would be set the new Id for an inserted task. 
        tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids(tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids.count +1).new_id := ltr.id + 100;
      
    END LOOP;
    
    FOR i IN tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids.FIRST..tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids.LAST
    LOOP
       --This works, could insert in loop but seems very inefficient and messy?
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids(i).old_id || ' ' || tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids(i).new_id);      
    END LOOP;
    
    --This would be the Inset Select rather than the returned cursor. 
    --INSERT INTO list_task_dependencies(
           --predecessor_task_id
           --, successor_task_id
          --, dependency_type
    --)    
    OPEN io_cursor FOR
    --Bits commented out that don't compile...
    SELECT DISTINCT --predecessor.new_id
           --, successor.new_id
           --, 
           ltd.dependency_type
    FROM list_task_dependencies ltd
          --TABLE(tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids) ERRORS =
          --Error: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
          --Error: PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
         --JOIN TABLE(tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids) predecessor ON predecessor.old_id = ltd.predecessor_task_id
         --JOIN TABLE(tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids) successor ON successor.old_id = ltd.successor_task_id
    ;
  END test_temp_table;
```

To help you understand where I am coming from it may be helpful to look at [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-variables/) to see how table variables work in MS sql server. Essentially I want a variable which holds relational data that I can query like a table. I know about global temporary tables obviously but that seems like a very messy solution to me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some sample data (preferably as DDL/DML statements we can copy/paste and execute) and your expected output for that sample data. Having a concrete example will help us to understand what you are trying to achieve as the description feels a little opaque.

Comment: Also, you probably want to drop the `INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER` from your data type and make it into a collection rather than an associative array. And, if you are going to use it in SQL statements then you'll need to declare the collection in the SQL scope (using `CREATE TYPE`) rather than in the PL/SQL scope as you can't use the latter in SQL statements. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=40b6e58129ada536d208f47b8bf8910b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't follow all the details of what you are trying to build, but a simplified example of adding an element to an associative array of records would be something like this:

```sql
declare
    type old_id_new_id_row is record(old_id number, new_id number);
    type t_old_task_ids_new_task_ids is table of old_id_new_id_row index by pls_integer;
    mycoll t_old_task_ids_new_task_ids;
    c pls_integer;
begin
    mycoll(1).old_id := 1;
    mycoll(1).new_id := 2;

    -- Or instead of specifying the array index, use the current count +1:
    mycoll(mycoll.count +1).old_id := 3;
    mycoll(mycoll.count).old_id := 4;

    -- Or a variable:
    c := mycoll.count +1;
    mycoll(c).old_id := 5;
    mycoll(c).new_id := 6;
    
    -- From 18c:
    mycoll(mycoll.count +1) := old_id_new_id_row(7,8);
end;
```

The pseudo-constructors in 18c are known as [Qualified Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-4B379569-4068-4DB1-9D69-E706F4AC5758) (they are not strictly constructors because a record type is not an object type and doesn't have object features, but the compiler helpfully does the same job for you).

I personally prefer `pls_integer` to `binary_integer` even though [they are the same thing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-9517B7AC-9CEA-4C36-A454-52588BEEBE8F), because for a long time `binary_integer` was deprecated and `pls_integer` was the replacement. Eventually Oracle merged the two, so you can use whichever one you like the sound of.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54894802/insert-into-table-from-collection-type-oracle-12c-ora-00902-invalid-datatype) INSERT SELECT from a TABLE TYPE collection into a Table. I have no idea why but you can't. Maybe I should have used Global Temp Table which didn't feel right to me but perhaps is more acceptable in Oracle.

So I had to loop through my Table Type inserting row by row which maybe again isn't as bad in Oracle as it is in MS SQL Server.

I couldn't use a Table Type that was declared at the procedure level, had to be done at the package level. There were a few other mistakes in my first attempt above.

This isn't the proc but gives you the idea. Took me basically a day+ to get here for something that I thought should take a couple of hours tops :(.

```
 TYPE old_id_new_id_row       IS RECORD(old_id list_tasks.id%TYPE, new_id list_tasks.id%TYPE);
 TYPE t_old_task_ids_new_task_ids IS TABLE OF old_id_new_id_row INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;


  PROCEDURE test_temp_table(list_id       IN lists.id%TYPE
                            , io_cursor   IN OUT t_ref_cursor) IS
    
    CURSOR lt (pc_list_id    lists.id%TYPE) IS
        SELECT id
        FROM list_tasks
        WHERE list_id = pc_list_id
        ;        
       
    lt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids t_old_task_ids_new_task_ids;
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  
    FOR ltr IN lt(list_id) LOOP  
        tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids(tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids.count +1).old_id := ltr.id;
        --This would be set the new Id for an inserted task. 
        tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids(tt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids.count).new_id := ltr.id + 100;
      
    END LOOP;
    
   FOR new_dependency IN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT predecessor.new_id AS predecessor_task_id
             , successor.new_id AS successor_task_id
             , ltd.dependency_type
        FROM list_task_dependencies ltd
           JOIN TABLE(lt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids) predecessor ON predecessor.old_id = ltd.predecessor_task_id
           JOIN TABLE(lt_old_task_ids_new_task_ids) successor ON successor.old_id = ltd.successor_task_id
    )
    LOOP
       INSERT INTO list_task_dependencies
       (
          successor_task_id
          , predecessor_task_id
          , dependency_type
       )
       VALUES
       (
          new_dependency.successor_task_id
          , new_dependency.predecessor_task_id
          , new_dependency.dependency_type
       );
    END LOOP;

  END test_temp_table;
```

Comment: The `table of ... index by` syntax defines an associative array, which is best suited to array processing but can be cast somewhat awkwardly to a pseudo-table with some restrictions, as you have found. You can query it via the `table()` operator but it's not really a table at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help, is there another way you might have approached this?

Comment: The `for new_dependency in ... loop ... insert` could be rewritten as an `insert select`. I'd look for a way to take the query used to populate the collection and use it to drive the insert, perhaps in a `with` clause (CTE) if that would make it simpler.